# Example: Writing the joint PDF $f(x, y)$ as the product of a marginal and a conditional probability function

Tags: probability, density-function, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution, bivariate

I am presented with the following notes on **Bivariate distribtions**:

> If we can write the joint probability density function $f(x, y)$ of a pair of random variables $(X, Y)$ as the product of a marginal and a conditional probability function, say, $f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x)$, then it is quite easy to generate samples. We first sample $x$ from $f(x)$ and then, given the $x$ sampled, we sample a value from $f(y|x)$. Thus, we have to sample twice from univariate distributions, and we can use any of the methods described in the previous sections.
>
> For example, take the joint probability density function:
>
> $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{4} &\text{if } -1 \le x \le 1 \ \text{and} \ x^2 - 1 \le y \le x^2 + 1 \\ 0& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>
> Then $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $−1 \le x \le 1$ and $0$ otherwise, i.e. $X$ has marginally a uniform distribution on $[−1,1]$. Furthermore, $f(y|x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $x^2 − 1 \le y \le x^2 + 1$ and $0$ otherwise, i.e. $Y$ has, conditionally on $X = x$, a uniform distribution on $[x^2 − 1, x^2 + 1]$.

My question is, how did the authors come to the conclusions in the last section:

> Then $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $−1 \le x \le 1$ and $0$ otherwise, i.e. $X$ has marginally a uniform distribution on $[−1,1]$. Furthermore, $f(y|x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $x^2 − 1 \le y \le x^2 + 1$ and $0$ otherwise, i.e. $Y$ has, conditionally on $X = x$, a uniform distribution on $[x^2 − 1, x^2 + 1]$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: You might see the point more clearly by pondering a generalization: you can replace the role of $x^2$ in this question by any (measurable) function.  This can be even further generalized: suppose $U\subset (-1,1)\times \mathbb R$ is a region for which the intersection of any vertical line $x=a$ and $U$ has total length $2$ when $-1\lt a\lt 1.$ Define $f(x,y)=1/4$ on $U$ (and $f(x,y)=0$ for all other points.)  The conclusions given in the question continue to hold.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand what question you're attempting to address. I'm specifically asking how the authors came to the conclusion that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $−1 \le x \le 1$, and $0$ otherwise, and $f(y|x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if $x^2 − 1 \le y \le x^2 + 1$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I am responding to your request to clarify this by inviting you to apply an ancient method (it goes back to Archimedes, far antedating the development of integral Calculus), [Cavalieri's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).  Drawing a picture of the region along with some of its vertical slices might help the intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a series of integrations:
$$f(x)=\int_{y\in R} f(x,y)dy=\int_{x^2-1}^{x^2+1}\frac{1}{4}dy=\frac{1}{2}, \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1$$
$$f(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}=\frac{1/4}{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}, \ \ x^2-1\leq y\leq x^2+1$$

What is suggested in the comments is a generalization in the case when some $g(x)$ is used instead of $x^2$ anywhere in the question.